# Sonarcloud + Gitlab import project API?

Tags: automation, gitlab, sonarcloud

I am using Sonarcloud and the gitlab integration they offer. In the UI (at the https://sonarcloud.io/projects/create url), they have a screen that looks like this (see screenshot) that allows the user to import a gitlab project from the gitlab organization they have setup.

[image]

I am trying to automate our gitlab and sonarcloud integration, and I am trying to figure out how to achieve this step automatically.

Does anyone know if Sonarcloud has an API endpoint that would allow me to automate importing a project into Sonarcloud from Gitlab?

Or is the only option for Sonarcloud users is to manually select the projects they want to import using the “Analyze projects” UI?

I've asked this question on the [sonarcloud community forums](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarcloud-gitlab/17792/20), but have had no luck in garnering a response.

Thanks in advance!